# Knockout JS - display template based on clicked link

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a single page application with some mocked up data. I am displaying an unordered list. The list is nested. When you click on an item in the list depending on the item clicked it sets two properties in my VM, either "selectedLayer" or "selectedProgramme". A layer is nested under a programme.

When a layer is clicked I call a function which sets the "selectedProgramme" to the parent - everything is fine up to that point. I now want to display different content based on the type of the layer. I have 3 templates but I want to show one one template based on the value of "layerType" of the "selectedLayer".

Hopefully this is clear - I have put all my code in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AzVbR/9/

Typically I can't get the data to display in my fiddle, but as you can see I have the following HTML to determine the layer type and then somehow use the correct template:

```
<div id="layerDetails" data-bind="template: { name: $root.displayLayerType }">
</div>
```

I did try passing 2 parameters, the programme object and $data but I wasn't sure what I was doing.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: Changed js fiddle link with working code as advised.

Comment: Please check for errors in your fiddle, and fix them.  In chrome press F12 and click on the console tab.  It'll show you errors, and you can click on the link to see the code line.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle as advised - thanks for that. I didn't include jQuery in my resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose template based on some value: when you bind template use as a name function that will return proper name:

```
this.displayLayerType = function() {
            if ( self.selectedLayer() ) {
                return self.selectedLayer().layerType.toLowerCase()+"-template";
            } else {
                return "error-template";
            }
    };
```

But your code has some more mistakes. To make it work you need to fix your templates, drop parenthesis `()` for observables. You shouldn't use them in HTML (there is an exception for evaluating expression).

```
<script type="text/html" id="treaty-template">
    <!-- ko with: $root.selectedLayer -->
    <h5 data-bind="text: LayerTitle"></h5>

    <p><!--ko text: layerType --><!--/ko--></p>
    <p>Treaty value: <span data-bind="text: treatyValueThing"></span></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

Here's working fiddle with those and other changes: http://jsfiddle.net/AzVbR/11/
I probably shouldn't remove jquery and it's DOM ready event.

Your implementation of passing more arguments is done properly and is documented in knockoutJS documentation.

And there is a problem with setting `selectedLayerType` and `selectedLayer`. You probably intend to use first for choosing template and second is the data. But you set one after another so knokoutjs sometimes have different data and different template name based on `selectedLayerType` not updated yet or vice versa. So my `displayLayerType` function is based only on `selectedLayer` and its `layerType` property. It's cleaner and simpler (less places for bugs) but if you really need it your way, with two observables you can do it. Search for silent update of observables. Update one of them silently and then let the other bubble the mutation.

Comment: That's great, it looks like it's just what I need. However I am struggling to understand elements of the solution. What is "event" in the anonymous function for each <li> item? Also what does bind(self) do?

Comment: Event has information about 'click', mouse position and others. It's not necessary for your problem. I've just rewritten it from knockout docs as is, see Note 2: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html Bind ensures that 'this' inside function equals 'self'. It's also not necessary but it's a good practice that I've learned while reading stockoverflow.

Comment: That's great - thank you for the detailed answer and follow up comments. It's been very helpful, appreciate it :)